# How to set up monaco-editor and change value?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I want to use the monaco-editor to look at different files of a directory. I want to create an editor and change the content dynamically. But it doesn't work the way I want it to.

```js
function doSomething(val) {
  require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'min/vs' }});
  require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
    monEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("content"), {
      value: val,
      language: "plain",
      scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
      readOnly: true
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<link type="text/css" href="min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
<!--- Modal start -->
<div id="content" style="height:100px; width: 100px;"> </div> <!-- Modal content -->
<!-- Modal end -->

<button onclick="doSomething('Input1')"> Change1 </button>
<button onclick="doSomething('Input2')"> Change2 </button>

<script src="min/vs/loader.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. The first time i open the modal everything works fine but than the monaco-editor disappear.

When i try to use `monEditor.setValue(val)` an error appear that monEditor is not defined.

And when i try to use `monEditor.setModel(model)` an error appear that the node is not found.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to change to make it work? I've tried a lot, but I don't get the editor set up right. 
Unfortunately, the examples don't help me either, because they include data that is not in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses scopes, which are small contexts of execution. Variables declared within a scope may be accessible ("visible") to sub-scopes of the current scope, but not to any outer ones. (See [the definition on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and [this comprehensive guide to JavaScript's scopes](https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/).)

You are defining your `monEditor` variable inside of a function scope, which is why you are not able to access it any time later. You can redefine your function as follows:

```
let monEditor;

function doSomething (val) {
    require.config ({ paths: { 'vs': 'min/vs' }});
    require (['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
        monEditor = monaco.editor.create (document.getElementById ("content"), {
          value: val,
          language: "plain",
          scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
          readOnly: true
        });
    });
}
```

Here `monEditor` is defined on the global scope, making it available to all functions. Trying to redeclare it will throw an error because `monEditor` is declared with `let`.